# Multiple readings from one change on a light sensor with interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno

I was trying to make a code which did something every time a light dependent resistor was covered up by using interrupts so I could be running a different code at the same time.
This was my finalised code:

```
#define LIGHT 2

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LIGHT, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(LIGHT), fall, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.print("Hello");
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}

void fall(){
    Serial.print("Light Covered!");
    Serial.println();
}
```

I have tested my ldr circuit (5V into the ldr with a 10k pulldown resistor) and it reliably sits over the digital read boundary so I don't need to use analog read. It also seems to have no bounce as if I read it by outputting a message every time it reads it as high and then waiting until it goes low it only reads once every time I cover it and uncover it. However for some reason the code above which uses interrupts seems to print light covered 3-7 times every time I cover it. I am quite new to arduinos and C although I have used python for a while so sorry if it is a silly noob mistake.

Comment: Don't use an interrupt. The arduino environment is not the same as an embedded system. Interrupts can often be avoided. Read the analog value in the loop. Add hysteresis. Do you want to detect a certain fixed value or a change in the value?

Comment: do minimum amount of work inside an ISR  ...... raise a flag only ...... print the message inside the `loop()` block whenever the flag is raised

Comment: @Jot I want to detect when the signal gets below a certain bound and the reason I want to use an interrupt is because then I can be monitoring serial while also detecting and doing something every time the signal falls

Comment: @jsotola But surely then the code inside the `loop()` still has to be checking to see if the flag has been raised so if it is doing something like continually checking serial it would not check it as often if it is checking the flag

Comment: i think that you have a misconception about how fast the arduino operates

Comment: @jsotola possibly as I'm used to python which is slow. If I was trying to pick up serial signals to tell it to send data back would it still be fast enough to do the monitoring inside `loop()`

Comment: basically, do not use any print statements or wait statements inside the ISR ................ do not use `delay()` in loop() either ........ refer to `BlinkWithoutDelay` example sketch that is included  in the Arduino IDE

Comment: I think, when you didn't use interrupts you achieved enough debouncing with the duration of your main loop. When using interrupts you might have to debounce the resistor yourself. Bit you have to do this in the loop, just raise a flag in the isr